# i have removed a tables column named stock.but when i am appliying migration it causes error?how can i rectify

Tags: django

```
raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
```

django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration figgyapp.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('figgyapp', '0003_remove_product_s
tock')

Comment: Looks like you deleted some migrations, get them from VCS, migrate them with --fake and migrate to migration before one you want to delete